# Updating property of object within stored array - React Native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-native

I am using [react-native-simple-store](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store) and have written the below function to update the property of a supplied object stored in an array of objects. To do so, I used the method mentioned in [issue #31](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store/issues/31) for deleting items.

Trouble is since I'm using .push, updating an item causes it to be rendered at the bottom of the array. This causes items to move in the FlatList unnecessarily.

Is there a more efficient method for updating a property of an object within the array (without causing this issue using .push)?

```
plusProgress = (itemId, progress) => {
  const foods = this.state.foods.filter(({ id }) => itemId !== id);
    const updatedItem = {
      itemId,
      progress: progress + 1
    };
  foods.push(updatedItem);
  this.setState({ foods });
  store.save('foods', foods);
}
```

Comment: What is `store`?

Comment: `store` is a reference to an imported wrapper around AsyncStorage (from react-native-simple-store).

Comment: So this saves data more permanently in a database or file system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new array with the updated object in the correct position, then call setState() with that new array. Be sure to return the current item as-is if is not the one you are trying to update. Otherwise, array elements will be replaced by null

```
  plusProgress = (itemId, progress) => {

  const foods = this.state.foods.map(item => {
    if (item.itemId === itemId) {
      return Object.assign({}, item, {progress: progress + 1});
    } 
    return item      
  })

  this.setState({ foods: foods })
}
```

Comment: I've read that changing values in state directly is not safe. Note that `const foods` is **not** a copy. It is a reference to the array from `this.state`.

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice! I can't comment your solution. So, I rewritten my solution to fix a little bug in your code.

Comment: Awesome! Yes, that is the part I missed. I will just delete my answer then.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for the reply, when I run this function it removes the value assigned to `progress:` I.e. it goes from `progress: 0` to `progress:` rather than to `progress: 1`

Comment: @garethiv What do you mean by `progress:`? Where do you see this? How is the function called? What is passed as the `progress` parameter? Is this parameter needed? Can you just use `item.progress` instead?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have it working, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You may try not immutable adding to array

```
foods.concat(updatedItem);
```

More about mutating and non-mutating array methods here
https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting the object from the list, replace it with an updated version:

```
plusProgress = (itemId, progress) => {
    const foods = this.state.foods.map(food => {
        if (itemId === food.id) {
            return Object.assign({}, food, {progress: progress + 1});
        }

        return item;
    });

    this.setState({foods});
}
```

To be more accurate, you probably should remove the `progress` parameter from `plusProgress()` and use `item.progress` instead. This ensures that you increment the current progress value rather than rely on passing an unrelated value to the function.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, when I used this it changed my object's `id` to undefined forcing me to have to reset storage

Comment: @garethiv I might not have the code here exactly correct. The basic concept is sound, though: create a new array with the updated object in the correct position, then call `setState()` with that new array. I leave it to you to fill in the correct details and debug the code. Note that it is difficult to give a completely correct answer because you have not provided a complete definition of your component. I am inferring the shape of `this.state` from very limited information.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll have a tinker and see if I can crack it... `this.state.foods` is an array of objects, each object with 7 properties.

Comment: And one of those properties is `id`, correct? Double check that you copied the code from my answer correctly. I don't see any reason why this code should set the `id` to undefined. There may be a bug elsewhere in your code.